# Show NSSegmentedControl menu when segment clicked, despite having set action

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, controls

My question is based on another question. Instead of repeating a bunch of stuff, I hope it's okay that I refer you to that other question instead:

[Show NSSegmentedControl menu when segment clicked, despite having set action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203698/show-nssegmentedcontrol-menu-when-segment-clicked-despite-having-set-action/)

My question is: How would the code within [self showGearMenu] look like, i.e. how would one actually use the popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView method to accomplish what the poster of the other question wants?

I ask because it seems that the question was resolved for the poster, but he never shared with us how he actually popped up the menu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this question a couple months ago, which I asked on Cocoa-dev:

http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/275771-trouble-with-nssegmentedcontrol.html#275771

The code that was emailed to me off-list works great, but it's not my code, so I'm going to post it.  However if you'd like it, contact Seth at Araelium Group about `AGNSSegmentedControl`: http://www.araelium.com/

Answer (score 4):

http://www.sethwillits.com/temp/AGNSSegmentedControl.h (also .m)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to do this, and the following looks almost exactly like the system presentation:

```swift
final class MenuSegmentedControl: NSSegmentedControl {

    @objc
    func showMenu() {
        var menuOrigin = frame.origin

        // magic number that gives just the right spacing between the button and the menu
        menuOrigin.y -= 4

        // this takes advantage of the enclosing menu item
        menu(forSegment: 0)?.popUp(positioning: enclosingMenuItem, at: menuOrigin, in: superview)
    }
}
```

I only have a single segment, though. This is a toolbar item that's meant to look like the Flag segment in Mail.app. In the `action`, it calls `showMenu()` on the segmented control.