# Can I change the NSSegmentedControl popup menu position?

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu, nssegmentedcontrol

I am using a 3 segment NSSegmentedControl for adding and removing configurations, as well as the cog "action" symbol to pop up a menu.

However, when the menu pops up it shows up as follows:

[image: Bad Popup Position]

I would much prefer the popup to be displayed centered above the cog segment instead below and sticking off the bottom of my window (which is actually a preference pane).

I have created a subclass of NSSegmentedCell to override the 'action' method as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203698/show-nssegmentedcontrol-menu-when-segment-clicked-despite-having-set-action).

I would prefer to avoid private APIs if at all possible!

Comment: How are you currently drawing the menu. It's actually possible for any button to display a menu when clicked. So get the behaviour you want, go the full manual route and display the menu your self (as part of the API to do this you have to specify the location of the menu).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, this is exactly what I have had to resort to... though one little thing I don't like is the cog button doesn't get the nice indented look when I pop up my menu... but I can live with that!